# What is the different of . and ./ in RUN

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I got best practice of vue dockerfile like this :

```
FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
```

I wonder what is the different of the target like first COPY ./ and second COPY . ?

Comment: In your example there is no difference. You can check more on COPY here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy

Answer (score 3):

When you have several sources, you are obligated to use `./` form, which explicitly specifies that the target is a folder, into which all sources are copied. So, `COPY a b ./` will make `./a` and `./b` inside container.

When you have single source like `COPY . .` this command **merges** source folder content into destination folder or replaces the file (if source is a file).

Best shown in an example. Lets say you have:

```
a/
  a.txt
b/
  b.txt
Dockerfile
hello.txt
```

**Dockerfile**

```
COPY hello.txt ./hello1    # will create/replace ./hello1 FILE in container
COPY hello.txt ./hello2/  # will create ./hello2/hello.txt 
COPY a .     # now you have ./a.txt in container
COPY b .     # now you have ./a.txt and ./b.txt in container
```

Finally you get in container:

```
hello1
hello2/hello.txt
a.txt
b.txt
```